# Debug issues in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android app which uses another android library module as a dependency. The thing is that I am unable to see the value of variables in that library during debug. As a result, I am also unable to evaluate expression also. I get an error saying 'Local Variable Not Found'. Any clues how to get around this issue?

Comment: Please post code and logcat

Comment: There is nothing in the logcat. And it is happening everywhere in d library code so how will it help? The thing is debug points are working but i am unable to see variable values(in library module) but i can see them in the main app module

Comment: If you are using the direct value of variable ,I am not sure how that would work .retrieve the value from library and use in your own variable with the returned value .now if you evaluate you should be able to see .

Comment: That wont suit my usecase. Actually i have the network layer in my library. So i need to debug the response string before it gets parsed

Comment: If it says local variable isn't found, then that means your variable you are inspecting is not in the scope of the breakpoint. Maybe you could include a screeenshot?

Comment: also see: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93730

Answer (score 0):

Try to add breakpoints in the library code.We can debug library code and can evaluate the expressions.

Comment: I am able to debug it. But unable to evaluate expression. It says local variable not found

Comment: Which library you are using?

Comment: It is my own code only. I needed to make two apps using the same code but lil tweaks so i turned it into a library

Comment: Any clue?I am still not able to do it

Comment: What was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `testCoverageEnabled true` in either your app or library's `build.gradle`, try switching it to false see if that fixes(works around) the problem. It does for me.

See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78045